# How do I display my Json Objects on a web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I am working on a ASP.NET Web Api and I'm having an issue figuring out how to display data to the api.

So to explain what I need to figure out. After accessing the objects from the Json file and [converting JSON to a .NET type.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithLinq.htm) I believe I should be able to display these on the api?

For example, whatever field I ask for, it should return the result sorted by that field.
Now I need to display this data in different ports. For example.

- https://host:port/api/books returns all unsorted (Book1-Book13)
- https://host:port/api/books/id returns all sorted by id (Book1-Book13)
- https://host:port/api/books/id/1 returns all with id containing '1' sorted by id (Book1, Book10-13)

I have followed this [tutorial by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#register-the-database-context) and the application seems to be working in regards to starting and using different ports.

This is the code I have set up in my controller class `BooksController.cs`

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class BooksController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAllBooks()
    {
        string[] books = { "book1", "book2", "book3" };

        if (!books.Any())
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(books);
    }

    [HttpGet("id/{id}")]
    public string GetBookById(int id)
    {

        return $"book: {id}";
    }

    [HttpGet("author/{author}")]
    public string GetBookByAuthor(string author)
    {
        return $"author: {author}";
    }
```

This is my `startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        GetAllBooks();
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
                                           opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }

    
    public void GetAllBooks()
    {
        string _path = $"C:\\Users\\filip\\source\\repos\\NexerGroupApi\\NexerGroupApi\\books.json";

        string jsonFromFile;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(_path))
        {
            jsonFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var booksFromJsonFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NexerGroupApi.Book>>(jsonFromFile);

        JArray bookArray = JArray.FromObject(booksFromJsonFile);

        IList<Book> bookList= bookArray.Select(p => new Book
        {
            Id = (string)p["Id"],
            Author = (string)p["Author"],
            Title = (string)p["Title"],
            Genre = (string)p["Genre"],
            Price = (string)p["Price"],
            Publish_date = (string)p["Publish_date"],
            Description = (string)p["Description"]
        }).ToList();
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Publish_date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

I wonder where I actually set up my `GetAllBooks()` method so that I can then access them in the `BooksController.cs` and be able to do api/books/bookNameFromJsonFile and show that specific object with all of it's contents such as id, author, title, genre, etc.

I know that my `IList<Book> bookList` in the class `startup.cs` does not work, for some reason every variable get's null value. Although not sure why.

Comment: @mason Okay so I've been looking at a couple tutorials now - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8iICilTuAs&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oVjOKgzsWqdFVvzGL2_d72v&index=6 - 

I will update my question and maybe you could answer to that?

Comment: You do not need to setup an individual route for every single book you have. You need to structure your route to have parameters. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis).

Comment: @mason Okay, I've checked out that link And a youtube video. As I understand it I then do for example [HttpGet("{id}")] and I then loop through my books in that method, then if I enter "api/book/2 it will retrieve the book where id=2.                 Does it work so that I can then do [HttpGet("{author}")] where I have a string author and so If I do api/books/authorname I will actually recieve the book/s from that author?

Comment: I edited the question to show you what I thought would work. Is there maybe an issue in my startup.cs that leads to this error code?

Comment: IDK if this could help, but try `[HttpGet("{id:int}")]`

Comment: It's your route definitions. Like the error says, your route matches multiple endpoints. Most likely it's mad because it can't tell which action method to hit for a URL like `/api/books/1`, it doesn't know whether `1` is an Id or an Author. For GetBookByAuthor, you might change it to `[HttpGet("author/{author}")]`, then someone who wished to look up books by author would hit the URL `/api/books/author/Tom%20Clancy`, and change GetBookById to `[HttpGet("id/{id}")]` so they can hit the URL `/api/books/id/1`. That makes it unambiguous. Just put some thought into how your structure the routes.

Comment: @mason 's description will be fix your problem. do not use `"{id}"` use `"id/{id}"` insted. Otherwise your urls would be match api/books/LordOfTheRings and also api/books/JrrTolkien both. This will throw `AmbiguousMatchException`

Comment: @mason Thanks for describing that part. That's what I misunderstood. Cant upvote as I have a new account but appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you have two routes that are ambiguous `[HttpGet("{id}")]` and `[HttpGet("{author}")]`

Given

When you hit api/books/1 the `1` could be the author or the bookid.

Consider changing the route of the author method to:
`[HttpGet("author/{author}")]`

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public string GetBookById(int id)
{
    
    return $"book: {id}";
}

[HttpGet("author/{author}")] 
public string GetBookByAuthor(string author)
{
    return $"author: {author}";
}
```

So requests would route as follows:

`api/books/1` would invoke `GetBookById`

`api/books/author/jsmith` would invoke `GetBookByAuthor`

Edit: Add list filtering:

To find a `Book` from the `List<Book>` then this can be done:

```
private readonly List<Book> _bookList; //populate this with books from json file

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetBookById(int id)
{
    var book = GetBookObjectById(id);
    if(book is null) return NotFound();
    return Ok(book);
}

private Book GetBookObjectById(int id)
{
    return _bookList.FirstOrDefault(book => book.Id == id);
}

private Book GetBookObjectByAuthor(string author)
{
    return _bookList.FirstOrDefault(book => book.Author == author);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I fixed this issue and have set up so that i can enter for example `api/books/id/1` or `api/books/title/bookTitle` . One thing im wondering about now is the following.. I get my Json data from a `file.json` Where do I setup this to load all the data? In the end I want to be able to do `api/books/bookNameFromJsonFile` and show that specific object with all of it's contents such as id, author, title, genre, etc. If you look at my `startup.cs` I have set it up there and then you can see how my `booksController.cs` looks like, is this the wrong way?

Comment: I updated my question so If you check it out now you can see where I'm at and what's bothering me. I haven't been able to find anything that I can really understand yet.

Comment: If this is just a learning exercise then I would personally just put the `loadbook` code you have in `Startup.cs` into the controller so it's created in the constructor. In a real world you'd make a `BookService` and inject it into the controller using dependency injection.

Comment: Your json deserialise code can also be greatly improved - take a look at the microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: This is more of a learning excercise than a real world scenario. I know I should be learning the correct way to begin with, but I have it easier learning this way then improving the code after I understand what I'm doing to begin with. Instead of just Ctrl+V everything. I have succesfully printed all the books now. But is there any way to print these as json objects? where id1 is in 1 {} and so on? This is how I display them `public ActionResult GetAllBooks(){if (!bookList.Any())return NotFound(); return Ok(bookList);}` but it's a complete hassle and cant be read.

Comment: Assuming you had `List<Book> bookList` with { Id=1, Title="Book1"} and {Id=2, Title="Book2"} then in your `GetById()` method, you would do `var foundBook = bookList.FirstOrDefault(book => book.Id = id);` then `return Ok(foundBook);` or if no book found with the id `return NotFound();`

Comment: I've added an example to the answer

Comment: Very interesting! I remade it to (string id) as Id is a string because it contains `B01` , `B02` and so on. Then you made one for Author as well. Do I do these for all different search criterias then? So remake the `GetBookByAuthor` to look like the `GetBookByID` method? Also I saw this `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.Indented);` I am to display these on a browser, but the formatting is just messed up. Can I use something like this to make it look like in PostMan when using the "Pretty" visualizer? Although add the `Formatting.Indented` somewhere else?

Comment: The formatting will be lost when returned to the client. It is down to the client (ie browser or postman) to format the json as required.

Comment: This answer helped me understand what approach I needed to take, and so I will mark it as the answer. Thank you.